# Flex Zoom DataGrid View

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, datagrid, data-visualization, advanceddatagrid

I'm looking to implement something in Flex that I believe I've seen before, but I have no idea what it's called in order to search for it. Maybe it's best described with an example...

Say I have a contact management application. I have a bunch of people, and each person has a bunch of data that I may or may not want to see at a quick glance. My solution would be to have two side by side grids. The left side would have only a couple of columns with straight text information, like "Bob Jones", "555-555-5555", "bobJones@gmail.com". Most of the time, when you're in the application, this would be the information you're looking for. The grid on the right side would be a "zoomed" view of a section of the left grid. So where the left side may have 20 rows visible, the right would have 5 rows visible. On the right grid you might have a picture, address, work info, etc that makes for a row that is too tall to fit in the left.

The closest example of this I can think of is [this timeline](http://visunetdemos.demos.ibm.com/webdemos/timeline/timeline.html), but turned 90 degrees to the right.

Does anyone know where I can find an existing control or tutorial that would help accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your example is the right-hand grid displaying data for one row or multiple rows? It sounds like you just need to bind the right-hand grid to the left-hand grid's selectedItem property. Then when the user selects an item more detailed information will be displayed about it.

Comment: The right-hand grid would be displaying multiple rows based on what range was selected in the left, much like the timeline link lets you select a range on the bottom and shows an expanded view up top.